# cannot see wifi network after instaling driver

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager

I am currently using ubuntu 16.04 and the wifi adapter I have is rtl8723be.
I have installed the appropriate drivers and the wifi worked decently until now, I just created a wifi hotspot recently, but after that I cannot find the list of wifi networks available , even when I am right below the router. The only way I am able to connect is via connect to hidden network, although by that I get proper speed, but the wifi icon above shows no  network,(i.e. the wifi signal icon is fully grey rather than fully white/ partially white) any solutions?

Comment: Do you see anything here `sudo iwlist scan`?

Comment: yes , there is a lot of info given including some 'Interface doesnt support scanning'

Comment: on the output above, try to see if you see your wi-fi (it should be at the beginning and your wi-fi name should be at `ESSID`). Post the output of your wifi. Then try `sudo systemctl restart network-manager, this should reset your network, can you connect after the reset?

Comment: Cell 17 - Address: 88:F0:77:BE:90:63
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=52/70  Signal level=-58 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"CAMPUS_SECURED"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s

Comment: this was small part of the large output, the output gave information about all the wifi networks available

but after I ran the command sudo systemctl restart network-manager, my wifi got connected with the hotspot network I created in my laptop(I dont know how)

Comment: If it helped please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart your Network manager with:

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

This usually does the job.

Comment: it restarted the wifi only to connect it to the hotspot network configured in my laptop